# How to get all Properties of an Operator

Tags: python, scripting

I want to show all properties of an operator in a panel or dialog and use them to execute the operator.

For Example the `transform.resize (TRANSFORM_OT_resize)` Operator. 
This Operator has 22 Properties without the 'rna_type' property in the first item. 
You can check this with this command: `bpy.ops.transform.resize.get_rna_type().properties`
It is possible to get all the Properties with this method. The only Problem is that the items of the Enumproperties are empty.

Another possibility was to draw the operator and then draw the properties of the operator. The problem with this method is, that I can't access the values and also the operator is shown.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?